# Measurement of asset quality

Tags: asset-pricing, banks, banking-regulations, asset, stress-testing

In the context of liquidity risk management in a commercial bank, what are the industry best practices to measure the quality of assets? Is it a percentage between 0 and 100, where the higher the percentage, the higher the asset quality? I'm interested not only in securities such as bonds, but also loans issued by the bank.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.federalreserve.gov/supervisionreg/topics/asset_quality.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see  it describes how to measure asset quality, can you be more specific?

Comment: look at https://www.federalreserve.gov/publications/files/bhc-4000.pdf  4020.2 for example.